# Unix command for searching multiple keywords

Tags: linux, unix, grep

Need to check in the error log on UNIX server for multiple sites, ex. lets say there are 3 sites ABC.com, XYZ.com and  OPQ.com. i want to get error log from server for any of these sites lies.

I tried with

```
tail -99999  /apache/log/error_log| grep 'ABC | XYZ | OPQ'
```

But was not working..

Comment: One way: grep -e "ABC" -e"XYZ" -e "OPQ'. Another way: grep -P 'ABC|XYZ|OPQ'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use egrep:

```
tail -99999  /apache/log/error_log| egrep '(ABC|XYZ|OPQ)'
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tail -99999  /apache/log/error_log| grep -E '(ABC|XYZ|OPQ)'
```

or

```
tail -99999  /apache/log/error_log| grep -e ABC -e XYZ -e OPQ
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
tail -99999  /apache/log/error_log | awk '/ABC|XYZ|OPQ/'
```